# Actionbarsherlock -- Setting a tab with higher index as the default tab

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using `Actionbarsherlock` for tab layout. In some conditions I want to set the tab at index 4 as the default tab. I mean the tab should stay at 5th position but it should be the default one. Is there any way to do that?

My class definition looks like this:

```
public class CalendarActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

and the `onCreate` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tabMonthly = bar.newTab();
    tabMonthly.setText("Monthly").setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tabMonthly);

    ActionBar.Tab tabWeekly = bar.newTab();
    tabWeekly.setText("Weekly").setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tabWeekly);

    ActionBar.Tab tabDaily = bar.newTab();
    tabDaily.setText("Day").setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tabDaily);

    ActionBar.Tab tabList = bar.newTab();
    tabList.setText("List").setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tabList);

    ActionBar.Tab addEvent = bar.newTab();
    addEvent.setText("Unread").setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(addEvent);


    //String callerActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("activityCaller");
    //if( callerActivity!= null && callerActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("notification") ){
        //bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(4);
    //}
}
```

I tried the code commented at the end of `onCreate()` method above. But the problem with this code is that it first loads the tab at index zero and then suddenly goes to tab at index4.